# Unable to refresh graph API token in node js

Tags: node.js, graph, refresh-token

Using angular SPA page to authenticate the user, I am trying to get a token and get subscription/notification flow in node js.  I am able to create a subscription to the mail box and am getting notification for the mails arriving in the  mail box.

The token received from the SPA is valid only for 24 hours after which it expires. I would like to get the refresh token for already created token in SPA from the node js, by checking the token expiry time.

Can some one share some light on this and share the process and sample code please.

I tried retrieving the token pass it to the node js and on getting a notification tried to refresh the token, if expired, but unable to do that as I am not having a refresh token.